# How to transfer props to the deepest component fast?

Tags: reactjs

I render React on a server.

I have a common chain of three components. I need to pass a `units` object (just plain js object `{name: 'example.com'}`) to the deepest component `<Foo />` in the chain from the most outer component `<FooBox />`. For now I have to pass my `unit` object down through every component as a `this.props.units`. I doesn't look nice, it looks like some bad practice to me:

```
// my-react-components.js file

var FooBox = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                // here I pass 'units'
                <FooList data={this.props.data} units={this.props.units}>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var FooList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                // and here I pass 'units'
                <Foo myId={this.props.data[0]} units={this.props.units} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Foo = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var units = this.props.units;  // and only here I use `units`
        return (
            // only here I need `units`
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: units[this.props.myId].name}}>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

On server-side my code is as follows (a Node.js app):

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
var FooBox = require('../my-react-components.js');

var data = [...some data here...];
var units = {name: 'example.com'}; // this is my 'units' object

var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(FooBox, {
    data: result,
    units: units // so 'units' comes yet from here
}));
```

My question is:

Is it the only way to get `units` in `<Foo />`? Only by passing it down the whole chain as a `props`? Is there a way to get `units` in `<Foo />` easier, avoiding step-by-step `props` passing?

Answer (score 1):

you can use context instead of props.It lets you pass data through the component tree without having to pass the props down manually at every level https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Comment: While this is a potential solution, I highly recommend against it. Not only is it an experimental API that is likely to change in the future, but it's very hard to read and understand. It's good for React as a framework as it can take more work off of the developer, but using it within your application is just going to make your code more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

For fast pass down `{...this.props}`.
For clear logic I think we must pass it down

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the large degree of redeclaring and reassigning the same properties down the component hierarchy tree is one of the more irritating features of React. It could be argued that this is a strength: the data flow is explicit and makes your application easy to reason about. But personally I find such repetition to be jarring.

Certainly context, as mentioned by vistajess, is one solution. But I am loath to invest much in an experimental API.

Another solution is to use Flux and have store listeners spread across different components. (In Redux for example, these would be contected components.) Of course this somewhat increases the complexity of your components.

Or finally you can just grin and bear it. (It's generally what I do.) Constantly re-typing the same properties may be annoying, but as far as code smells go its pretty minor. Bear in mind too that React is still fairly new and its API is rapidly evolving. In time, surely some solution to this problem will be adopted. (The mainstreaming of context perhaps?) For now, be comforted by the fact that React's weaknesses are far outweighed by its strengths.